# Spring security oauth2 client

Tags: java, spring-security

I've setup an OAuth2 server with spring security. I want to write client application to use this oauth server with spring security without protecting any resource. Means I just want to run oauth2 from client side with spring security 3.1. I have written the following configuration but it asks for credentials before redirecting to oauth2 server authorize page. But I want to redirect user to oauth2 server authorization page before asking any credentials from client side. I am using following configuration

```
<http auto-config='true' xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/product/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="jimi" password="jimi" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!--apply the oauth client context -->
<oauth:client id="oauth2ClientFilter" />


<oauth:resource id="fooClient" type="authorization_code"
    client-id="foo" client-secret="secret" access-token-uri="${accessTokenUri}"
    user-authorization-uri="${userAuthorizationUri}" scope="read" />


 <bean id="dService" class="com.abc.service.DServiceImpl">
    <property name="dURL" value="${dURL}"></property>
    <property name="dRestTemplate">
        <oauth:rest-template resource="fooClient" />
    </property>

 </bean>
```

So i just want /product url should access oauth2 server. Rest of the URL mapping should work without this.
And User should be anonymous for client ( No need to show login from on client side).

But When I run my application "http://localhost/client-sample/product/1" then it shows "http://localhost/client-sample/spring_security_login". But I want user should redirect to oaut2 server page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spring security prevents anonymous users from acquiring an access token. But if you still want this functionality in your application then you will have to extend org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails class and override isClientOnly() method.

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;

public class ExtendedBaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails extends
    AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails {

public boolean isClientOnly() {
    return true;
}
}
```

By default this method returns false. So you have to override this method to return true.
Then in your root-context.xml file you have to define oaut2 resource like this.

```
<bean id="fooClient" class="com.abc.service.ExtendedBaseOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails">
  <property name="clientId" value="foo"></property>
  <property name="clientSecret" value="secret"></property>
  <property name="accessTokenUri" value="${accessTokenUri}"></property>
  <property name="userAuthorizationUri" value="${userAuthorizationUri}"></property>
  <property name="scope" value="#{{'read','write'}}">   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dService" class="com.abc.service.DServiceImpl">
  <property name="dURL" value="${dURL}"></property>
  <property name="dRestTemplate">
      <oauth:rest-template resource="fooClient" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

This will not ask authorization on client side before redirecting the user to the oauth2 provider authorization page.